# Python Service launched with Popen have logging stderr & stdout redirection problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I want log all from my service, I'm launching it with:

launcher.py:

```
subprocess.Popen(['myservice.py'])
```

service.py:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler('/var/log/myservice.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(handler)
.....
```

But the problem is that stdout and stderr aren't writing in myservice.log

I was testing with:

```
with open("/var/log/myservice_out.log","w+") as out, open("/var/log/myservice_err.log","w+") as err:
        subprocess.Popen(['myservice.py'],stdout=out,stderr=err)
```

But this isn't using logging, and I want to log all messages(stderror,stdout) in only one file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is normal.

The logging module does NOT redirect stdout and stderr. It CAN write to stdout/stderr depending on what handler you configured, but it's not supposed to redirect stdout or stderr.

It seems you really want to use [os.dup2()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.dup2) in `service.py` or specify the `stdout` and `stderr` arguments to [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) in `launcher.py`

Comment: I understand that. You should evaluate whether this is a good answer to your question and maybe ask another, more specific question. Maybe about configuring logging handlers or about using os.dup2() or using stdout and stderr arguments to Popen(). Please do your homework.